# How to fudge Google Lighthouse PWA HTTP-redirect test with IIS express

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, iis-express, lighthouse

I don't have a valid SSL certified server at the moment (please don't ask why) and I'm using Chrome and remote debugging to try to get my PWA to pass the lighthouse-PWA tests so I can get the "Would you like to install this APP" prompt.

The problem is my IIS Express server is self-certified which doesn't pass the criteria but everything is good until lighthouse tries to invoke the APP via http instead of httpS and then it just hangs 'cos as you know IIS Express listens for httpS on something like port localhost:12345 and http localhost:22222.

I have rewrite rules to redirect http to httpS but this seems to change the destination port before lighthouse sees it :-(

How to I fudge the test so I can debug my PWA on my USB connected phone with only a self-certified server?

UPDATE:

To clarify, lighthouse connects to the server https://localhost:12345 and does some performance and functionality tests before checking that all http requests are converted to httpS requests. The problem is it tries http://localhost:12345 and IIS Express isn't listening for http on that port. The request eventually times out and Lighthouse fails the test as it did not get a response.

Comment: Self-signed certificates can be made trusted, so you don't really need valid certificates during testing. However, I can hardly see an error above. "it just hangs" is an invalid description, as there can be more hints if you use tools like Fiddler to follow the stream. Collect more data and get back to edit the question.

Comment: Please see the updates above